# How can I change this name?

Tags: macos

This **xue** drives me crazy, I don't know where it come from, how can I change it?
[image]

Comment: It is your home folder ?

Comment: That is your home folder - other users home folders will not have the house icon - and your screenshot does not show another users - what is your user name - shows in System Preferences -> Users & Groups

Answer (score -2, accepted):

That is your home folder. Since no other users are shown it must be that you named it that way.

To change it:

Open system preferences

Users

Unlock it (bottom left)

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> click (same as right click) on the account

Click on advanced options

Change the account name

Change the Home directory field to match the new name of the folder in /Users.

Click OK, and close the System Preferences screen.

Log out of the current administrator account, and into the original (renamed) account.

Here is a sample from my computer, only change the yellow marked fields, do not change anything else!

[image: user]

Comment: If you change the account name you also need to change the folder name on the disk and take care of a few other things.

Comment: Why so many down votes? This is the answer I am looking for.

Comment: @AveMaleficum glad I could help, I was wondering my self about my popularity !

Answer (score 4):

It's the current user's home directory. It should correspond to the currently logged in user (shown in System Preferences > System > Accounts). The name **xue** is the short name for the currently logged-in user.

If it's on your Mac and it isn't you and you don't recognise it, then you'd have to wonder who has an account on your Mac that you don't know about. Did you buy it secondhand maybe?

You can rename user accounts - see [Apple's support website for more info](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1428).

Comment: Since the folder has the 'home' icon, it's not just any home folder, it's the currently logged in user's home folder.